# Horizontally align a stretched image inside a div?

Tags: css, horizontal-alignment

How can I horizontally align - at an arbitrary percentage - a stretched/scaled image inside a div?

See the html below. The image needs to be horizontally aligned inside the div, by an arbitrary percentage.
So, `0%` = left, `50%` = centered, `53%` = *almost* centered, and `100%` = right

```js
// just a toggle script, not relevant to the question
const toggle = function() {
    const viewportElement = document.querySelector('.viewport');
    if (viewportElement.classList.contains('viewport--portrait')) {
        viewportElement.classList.remove('viewport--portrait')
    } else {
        viewportElement.classList.add('viewport--portrait')
    }
};
```

```css
.viewport {
    position: relative;
    margin: 60px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 667px;
    height: 375px;

}
.viewport--portrait {
    width: 375px;
    height: 667px;
}

.btn_toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* *** relevant styles below *** */

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* ???? */
}

.image-wrapper img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport viewport--portrait">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nigSBoN.jpeg" width="1952" height="765" alt="Chocolate!">
        </div>
        <button class="btn_toggle" onclick="toggle();">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="chocolate.jpg" width="1952" height="765" alt="Chocolate!">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a method to consistently horizontally align stretched images?

Comment: only left,right,center or you can have something like 25%, 33%, etc ?

Comment: It should work for any percentage, `15%`, `38%`, `97%`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```css
  position: relative;
  left: var(--p);
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var( --p)));
```

on the image element then simply adjust the variable to define the percentage:

```js
// just a toggle script, not relevant to the question
const toggle = function() {
  const viewportElement = document.querySelector('.viewport');
  if (viewportElement.classList.contains('viewport--portrait')) {
    viewportElement.classList.remove('viewport--portrait')
  } else {
    viewportElement.classList.add('viewport--portrait')
  }
};
```

```css
.viewport {
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 667px;
  height: 375px;
}

.viewport--portrait {
  width: 375px;
  height: 667px;
}

.btn_toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}


/* *** relevant styles below *** */

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-wrapper {
  --p: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  left: var(--p);
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var( --p)));
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport viewport--portrait">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nigSBoN.jpeg" width="1952" height="765" alt="Chocolate!">
    </div>
    <button class="btn_toggle" onclick="toggle();">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. I tried the `left: var(x%); transform: translate(-x%);` and many variations thereof, on just about any element, except on the image itself :( Thanks for the solution!